# what is faster to read, ASCII or Binary?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I am presently working on a C++ project that involves reading in thousands of small (~20kb) text files which are all in ASCII format.

Will I be able to get a significant performance improvement by converting all of the files into Binary before analyzing them?

Comment: It depends on whether the data you are reading is numeric (numbers stored in the file as ASCII characters) or text-based. If it's numeric, then you'll absolutely get a performance boost if you read/write in binary. Why? because the computer won't have to translate between text numbers in the file and binary numbers in memory. If the data in the files is the text itself, there's little to be gained. Since this was asked 10.5 years ago, I'm guessing the OP has moved on, so this is more FYI for passers-by.

Answer (score 11):

Converting a string to a number, while not cheap in cpu cycles, is a non-issue.  The amount of overhead involved with I/O is always orders of magnitude larger than the conversion.  The size of the file is not much of an issue either, a disk supplies 8KB about as fast as 20KB, it all comes out of the same cluster on the same track.  Having thousands of files is a *big* issue, opening a file involves moving the disk reader head and that takes forever.

So focus on whittling down the number of files for a real gain.

Answer (score 6):

There is no real difference between "ASCII" and "Binary" if you're handling text.  ASCII is an interpretation of Binary data as text.  So, if I understand your question correctly, the answer is no, there is no conversion that is possible and there is no performance improvement.

Comment: The OP says they are reading in "text files", and if the data has meaning as strings, then you're correct. However, one can also store (e.g.) formatted numeric data in "text files". If that's the case, I/O is MUCH faster if the computer gets to read/write the numbers in its native language (binary) rather than having to translate between ASCII characters to binary numbers. It's a little unclear what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 5):

Storing data in binary format has two advantages:

- it occupies less storage (less disk IO)
- it is faster to read (no time-consuming string parsing)

So there will be performance improvements if you convert your textual representation to a tightly-packed binary format, but if they are *significant* depends on your particular situation.

If data streaming *is* already a performance bottleneck, switching to a binary format (and possibly even compressed - reading from disks is inherently slow ) can bring a lot.

Comment: "no time-consuming string parsing" - What do you mean by that? You still need to parse your input to store it in data structures right?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a performance gain on load when the binary format is such that you consequently minimise any requirement for parsing. For example, where the content can be dumped in large chunks that map directly into a 'struct dump'. Every further step beyond this in turn may cost you performance. Whether this ends up being much ahead of the ASCII will in part depend on how complex/inefficient the ASCII is to start with.

Steps which cost you even in binary include:

- Compression
- Platform independence
- Variable content
- Changes to the content requiring an update of the binary from the ASCII

If you are sure a large part of the execution time is load and parse, but you only do this once for a fixed data set, an other option might be to use threads. Set up a bunch of parallel workers that load the data and then place it on a queue for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, yes. But then it'll be impossible to verify the input files by inspection, and you'll have to spend time writing code to transcode them, and new code to read them. I'd only do it if you find that I/O time is a significant problem .